# How to use PHP with Visual Studio

Tags: php, visual-studio

First let me say I've never used PHP but I'm looking to learn it, so my question is this how do you use PHP within Visual Studio Ultimate? is it similar to how you declare JQuery i.e

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{ 
    // Code goes here?  
});
```

I've done multiple searches on Google, but I don't get the answer I'm looking for.

Or do I need a complete different bit of software to use it?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a simple editor like notepad++ or sublimetext or vi ? A great advantage of PHP is that you don't have to manage compilations or builds.

Comment: one can be used to work in Visual Studio; totally understand. Try http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5

Comment: Here is a solution at here (WebMatrix, free) : http://superuser.com/questions/644060/editing-php-in-microsoft-visual-studio-express-2012

Comment: this question references jQuery - a client side JavaScript library - i.e. it runs after HTML has been formulated and sent from the server to the browser...  but PHP runs server-side, and is used to create the HTML code that will be sent down to the browser.. so, that is no small distinction - and thus the two technologies are nowhere near similar

Answer (score 75, accepted):

By default VS is not made to run PHP, but you can do it with extensions:

You can install an add-on with the extension manager, [PHP Tools for Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5?SRC=VSIDE).

If you want to install it inside VS, go to Tools > Extension Manager > Online Gallery > Search for PHP where you will find PHP Tools (the link above) for Visual Studio. Also you have VS.Php for Visual Studio. Both are **not free**.

You have also a cool PHP compiler called Phalanger:
[image: Phalanger PHP Compiler]

If I'm not mistaken, the code you wrote above is JavaScript (jQuery) and not PHP.

If you want cool standalone IDE's for PHP: (Free)

- Netbeans: https://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=windows&lang=en&option=php
- Eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliosr

Comment: is this support PHP MVC??

Comment: was getting error on netbeans dl. New link? https://netbeans.org/downloads/

Comment: It is currently free to use Visual Studio CODE and the FREE version of PHP Tools for Visual Studio CODE. It probably makes more sense to use one of the above mentioned IDE's instead.

Answer (score 15):

Maybe we should help you with a big misunderstanding on your side first: PHP is (like ASP.NET or whatever you used to far) a **server side** language while javascript is **client side**.

This means that PHP will run on your webserver and create a HTML page dynamically which is then sent to the browser. Javascript in turn is embedded (either directly or as a referenced file) into this HTML page and runs in the browser.

Maybe you can now understand why your approach so far could never work out.

Comment: I just came across this and wanted to add a clarification for future visitors. PHP is a server-side scripting language, while ASP.Net is a server-side Web application framework. They are not comparable. One is a programming language, the other is a framework. ASP.Net allows you to use several different programming languages, such as C# and VB, to develop your web site/application.

Comment: @Anders You are absolutely right. I decided to keep it simple in order to concentrate on what seemed relevant to me. In this case the difference between server side and client side execution.

Answer (score 9):

Try **Visual Studio Code**. Very good support for PHP and other languages directly or via extensions. 
It can not replace power of Visual Studio but it is powerful addition to Visual Studio.
And you can run it on all OS (Windows, Linux, Mac...).

https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Visual Studio Code is quickly becoming the "catch-all" for things Visual Studio doesn't support. Like GoLang. Very versatile.

Comment: VSCode still doesn't support proper code formatting, it always insist on expanding your code like ruining your CSS and Javascript. but still works better than netbeans which still doesn't have vertical selection and doesn't even format HTML properly.

Comment: (I'm contributor to the extension below)
The complete PHP language support (debugging, IntelliSense, test explorer, code analysis, formatting, ...) provided with additional extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DEVSENSE.phptools-vscode

Answer (score 8):

Maybe it's possible to debug PHP on Visual Studio, but it's simpler and more logical to use [Eclipse PDT](https://eclipse.org/pdt/) or [Netbeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/features/php/) for your PHP projects, aside from Visual Studio if you need to use both technologies from two different vendors.

Comment: Off topic. The question is how to use PHP with visual studio. Been using VS php for 6 years, it's stellar and worth the price.

Answer (score 7):

Here are some options:

- [Visual Studio PHP (VS.Php)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsphp.VSPhpforVisualStudio).
- [PHP Tools for Visual Studio by DEVSENSE](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5).

Or you can check this list of [PHP editor reviews](http://php-editor-review.toptenreviews.com/).

Comment: I hardly not recommend VS.PHP
This thing is really buggy and cause frequent fatal crashes of VS (2013 x86 on W7 machine)

Comment: These both are not free, are there any tools which are free?

Comment: Visual Studio PHP link is going to an scam website now

Comment: @AaA: link updated to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsphp.VSPhpforVisualStudio

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand how other answers don't answer the original question about how to use PHP (not very consistent with the title).
PHP files or PHP code embedded in HTML code start always with the tag `<?php` and ends with `?>`.

You can embed PHP code inside HTML like this (you have to save the file using `.php` extension to let PHP server recognize and process it, ie: index.php):

```
<body>
   <?php echo "<div>Hello World!</div>" ?>
</body>
```

or you can use a whole php file, ie: test.php:

```
<?php    
$mycontent = "Hello World!";
echo "<div>$mycontent</div>";
?> // is not mandatory to put this at the end of the file
```

there's no `document.ready` in PHP, the scripts are processed when they are invoked from the browser or from another PHP file.

Comment: Ultimately I think the author wants to know how he can start using PHP within Visual Studio, like with compiling and debugging support.

Comment: @Crono Author actually doesn't have a clue about PHP and what it does. But this question was back in 2012.