# Passing Javascript Variable in embedded C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a function in C# which can be called like this:

```
string result = CachedLanguageItems.GetLabel("RandomLabel").Value
```

It returns me the cached value of the *RandomLabel*.
Now I want to use this method in Javascript like this:

```
var result = <%= CachedLanguageItems.GetLabel("RandomLabel").Value %>
```

This is also working. It returns me the cached value of *RandomLabel*.

The problem that I am facing now is, that I am not able to pass a javascript variable to the method instead of a hard coded string. e.g.:

```
var javascriptVariable= "RandomLabel"
var result = <%= CachedLanguageItems.GetLabel(javascriptVariable).Value %>
```

Can somebody tell me how to pass the javascript variable correctly to the embedded c# call of the method?

Do I have to escape the embedded code for this?
Is this even possible?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What environment are you using? What does 'embedded' mean in this context?

Comment: @rmorring, this looks like ASPX which is the .NET counterpart to PHP.

Comment: Read tag descriptions before adding! This is not relates to embedded devices!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. The C# code is evaluated on the server before the HTML is shipped to the browser. The JS code runs on the client (the browser). What you could do it write a small service which you call via AJAX that returns the value you need.

Please read my related answer to this on
[How to use PHP with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529214/how-to-use-php-with-visual-studio/10530072#10530072)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.