# VS Code Multiple Language highlighters for different languages in one File

Tags: editor, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

First of all, I have just migrated to **VS Code** for **Sublime Text** couple of days back.

what I want is to Multiple Language highlighters in one Language extension.

eg: I want to highlight the proper *ending tags* of `HTML`,`PHP` and `Javascript` inside `.php` file.

The only method I could find out was in the settings I added this following code:

```
"files.associations": {
        "*.php":"html, php"
 }
```

When I tried this the `.php` file only highlights the `HTML` syntax.

So is ***there any extension or any other way*** of achieving the result I want.?

Comment: What you're looking for sounds to be support for [embedded languages](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/embedded-languages) in whichever extension you're using to provide language support for the "outermost" language, or some similar effect achieved through other means. For the specific case of HTML in PHP, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/45947972/11107541.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a long way ***(always welcomes a better answers)***

The only way I came across is to change the language according to our need using shortcuts and after working change it back.

*eg:*

If we are working on `.php` file and you have to check the `html` syntax then.

Click - <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and after a little time click - <kbd>M</kbd>

this will bring a *Search Bar* just type the language you need in my case, `html` and this will make the default language `html` so `html` syntax highlighting will work fine after working you can do the same and change it back.

This can be done other way, just click on the `language(PHP)` you see at the bottom of the `VS code editor` then the *Search Bar*  will come and then follow the steps above.

Hoping this would be Helpful for you.'

***One more time - a better answer is always welcome***

Comment: This is a workaround alright, but I will be looking for more straight answers.!