# How to ignore SQL syntax in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

[image]

Hi, as the title implies, how do I ignore SQL syntax highlighting on my .php files?

As you could see on the image above, Visual Studio Code seems to think that the 
`'DELETE /api/crm/contact_meetings....'`
starts a SQL query and messes up the highlighting of the whole file.

I have tried checking the Visual Studio Code's settings but to no avail, I can't seem to find a relevant configuration entry for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48522183/4229270, try changing language

Comment: Have you ever tried to use an a try catch?

Comment: @FernandoUrban why would I use try catch?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and I fix it with the help of Crayons' post.

Just delete these lines!

> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS
>   Code\resources\app\extensions\php\syntaxes\php.tmLanguage.json

```
2531:       "sql-string-double-quoted": {
2532:           "begin": "\"\\s*(?=(SELECT|INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE|CREATE|REPLACE|ALTER|AND)\\b)",
2533:           "beginCaptures": {
2534:               "0": {
2535:                   "name": "punctuation.definition.string.begin.php"
2536:               }
2537:           },
2538:           "contentName": "source.sql.embedded.php",
2539:           "end": "\"",
2540:           "endCaptures": {
2541:               "0": {
2542:                   "name": "punctuation.definition.string.end.php"
2543:               }
2544:           },
2545:           "name": "string.quoted.double.sql.php",
2546:           "patterns": [
2547:               {
2548:                   "include": "source.sql"
2549:               }
2550:           ]
2551:       },
2552:       "sql-string-single-quoted": {
2553:           "begin": "'\\s*(?=(SELECT|INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE|CREATE|REPLACE|ALTER|AND)\\b)",
2554:           "beginCaptures": {
2555:               "0": {
2556:                   "name": "punctuation.definition.string.begin.php"
2557:               }
2558:           },
2559:           "contentName": "source.sql.embedded.php",
2560:           "end": "'",
2561:           "endCaptures": {
2562:               "0": {
2563:                   "name": "punctuation.definition.string.end.php"
2564:               }
2565:           },
2566:           "name": "string.quoted.single.sql.php",
2567:           "patterns": [
2568:               {
2569:                   "include": "source.sql"
2570:               }
2571:           ]
2572:       },
```

I'd have to add it as a comment to Crayons' post, but I can't because I'm completely new to here. Sorry. Hope it helps you.

Comment: A simple way. 1. Open file `%LocalAppData%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\php\syntaxes\php.tmLanguage.json`. 2. Find and remove `{"include":"#sql-string-double-quoted"},` and `{"include":"#sql-string-single-quoted"},`. 3. Save file.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to note, that I also experience this with the keyword DELETE. There is definitely something buggy with this keyword.

My investigations thus far, have led me to believe its either a language specific issue, or a theme specific issue.

PHP's language syntax highlight rules were taken from Atom's definitions -- see here: https://github.com/atom/language-php/blob/master/grammars/php.cson and here https://github.com/atom/language-php/issues/321

Visual Studio Code implemented this through `php.tmLanguage.json` which you'll find in `~\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\php\syntaxes`.

Or, its a theme specific thing which may be somewhere here `~\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\theme-defaults\themes`.

The VS Code team says any contributions or issues should be addressed with against the original repository (linked above). I've decided that its just not worth my time to investigate further, but you're welcome to try raising an issue over there :)

If you happen to find a fix, please let me know!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I found an easy answer.

Open ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\php\syntaxes\php.tmLanguage.json

search and replace the line (there's multiple instances)

```
SELECT|INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE|CREATE|REPLACE|ALTER|AND
```

with

```
SELECT|INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE FROM|CREATE|REPLACE|ALTER|AND
```

That will make sure that the SQL formatting only kicks in when "delete from" is used, while leaving the normal syntax highlighting intact.