# How can I get the html suggestion format back in VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I had to rename all my .html to .php files in order to be able to do a little bit of php code in them. But now when I'm writing html I lost all the 'hint suggestion' code for example: like when you open up `<div>` it will automatically type a `</div>` (closure) tag behind it. Same when inserting an image and going '`../images/`' it would help me locate the path with a dropdown.

How can I get these back in a .php file extension enviroment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to make Visual Studio Code recognize HTML syntax in PHP files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947972/is-there-a-way-to-make-visual-studio-code-recognize-html-syntax-in-php-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem I used this extension in vscode:
[vscode-intelephense-client](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client).

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not supported natively by VSCode. There is an issue currently open for that, check this out https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1751.

You have to use an external plugin such as:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client