# How do I make the project run on browser in VIsual Studio?

Tags: php, visual-studio, browser

I have a PHP web project and I want to run it on the browser. 
I can only see the run button which runs the project on terminal and not on the browser.

How do I make it run on the browser?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529214/how-to-use-php-with-visual-studio

Comment: The post will help you with your question